# Find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of the following integral equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, boundary-value-problem, integral-equations, eigenfunctions

I have the integral equation $$u(x)=1+\lambda \int_0^1 K(x,t)u(t)dt $$
$x \in (0,1)$,
$\lambda \in \mathbb{R} $
and $$K(x,t)=\begin{cases} x(t+1) & t \leq x \\ t(x+1) & x \leq t \end{cases} $$
Find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of the equation by first converting it into a boundary value problem.

I was able to convert the integral equation into an ODE, by splitting the integral from $0$ to $x$ and $x$ to $1$ i.e.
$$u(x)=1+\lambda \int_0^x x(t+1)udt +\lambda \int_x^1 t(x+1)udt$$ and differentiating  twice, which gave me the equation $$u''(x)=\lambda u(x)$$

I then attempted to find the boundary values,
I have $$u(0)=1+\lambda \int_0^1 tu(t)dt $$
$$u(1)=1+\lambda \int_0^1 udt+\lambda \int_0^1 tudt$$
$$u'(0)=0$$
$$u'(1)=\lambda \int_0^1 udt$$
Those values are related by $$u(1)=u'(1)+u(0)$$

So the boundary values are $$u(1)=u'(1)+u(0) \ \ (1)$$ and $$u'(0)=0 \ \ (2) $$

Now to find the eigenvalues I solve $$u''=\lambda u$$
The solution is $$u(x)=c_1e^{\sqrt{\lambda }x}+c_2e^{-\sqrt{\lambda }x } \ \ (3)$$

I now use the boundary values to find $c_1,c_2$  so
$$u'(0)=0=c_1-c_2$$
$$c_1=c_2$$
So $$u(0)=2c_1$$
$$u(1)=c_1(e^{\sqrt{\lambda } } +e^{-\sqrt{\lambda }} )$$
and $$u'(1)=c_1(\sqrt{\lambda } e^{\sqrt{\lambda }}-\sqrt{\lambda } e^{-\sqrt{\lambda }}) $$
By plugging those values in $(1)$ I get $$c_1(e^{\sqrt{\lambda }}+e^{-\sqrt{\lambda }}-e^{\sqrt{\lambda }} \sqrt{\lambda } + e^{-\sqrt{\lambda }} \sqrt{\lambda}-2)=0$$
$c_1$ can't be $0$ otherwise we would have the trivial solution so it must be true that $$e^{\sqrt{\lambda }}+e^{-\sqrt{\lambda }}-e^{\sqrt{\lambda }} \sqrt{\lambda } + e^{-\sqrt{\lambda }} \sqrt{\lambda}-2=0$$
Which is only true if $\lambda=0$ therefore $\lambda=0$ is the eigenvalue and if I plug $\lambda=0$ in the general solution of the ODE ($(3)$) I get $$u(t)=2c_1$$ so the eigenfunctions are constant.

Is my solution correct?